# OpenGL not drawing as expected

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl, glfw

I can't seem to get this program to work, I only get a black window instead of the expected red triangle and can't figure out why.

This is the code I have written:

```
#include "glfw3.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>


static unsigned int CompilaShader (unsigned int tipo, const std::string &source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader (tipo);
    const char* src = source.c_str ();
    int* risultato;
    int lenght;
    
    glShaderSource (id, 1, &src, nullptr); // crea shader
    glCompileShader (id); // compila shader
    
    // controllo errori
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, risultato);
    if (risultato == GL_FALSE)
    {
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &lenght);
        char* message = (char*) alloca (lenght * sizeof (char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, lenght, &lenght, message);
        
        std::cout << "Errore nella compilazione nel shader" << (tipo == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << std::endl;
        std::cout << *message << std::endl;
        
        glDeleteShader (id);
        return 0;
    }
    
    return id;
};

static unsigned int CreaShader (const std::string &VertexShader, const std::string &FragmentShader)
{
    unsigned int programma = glCreateProgram ();
    unsigned int vs = CompilaShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompilaShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FragmentShader);
    
    glAttachShader (programma, vs);
    glAttachShader (programma, fs);
    glLinkProgram (programma);
    glValidateProgram (programma);
    
    glDeleteShader (vs);
    glDeleteShader (fs);
    
    return programma;
};

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    unsigned int buffer;
    float posizioni [6] =
    {
        0.5f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f
    };
    
    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    
    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    
    std::string vertexshader =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "\n"
    "in vec4 position;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main ()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}\n";
    
    std::string fragmentshader =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main ()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   color = vec4 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)\n"
    "}\n";
    
    unsigned int shader = CreaShader (vertexshader, fragmentshader);
    glUseProgram(shader);
    
    unsigned int vao;
    glGenVertexArrays (1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray (vao);
    
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer); // crea buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer); // seleziona buffer come array
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof (float), posizioni, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // dati buffer
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
    glVertexAttribPointer (0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof (float) * 2, 0); // crea attributo posizione
    
    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        
        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I get no compilation errors/warnings and no error message from the `CompilaShader` function.

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with it?

Working on a MacBook with an NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB, which won't support anything older than OpenGL 3.3, running MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, using XCode 9.4.1.

Comment: You can't make `OpenGL` calls without a valid current context.  Try moving the call `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);` to a point immediately after the `if (!window) { ... }` check.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `core` GLSL without requesting a Core context?  Why aren't you checking for shader link failures via `glGetProgramiv()`+`GL_LINK_STATUS` & `glGetProgramInfoLog()`?

Comment: Why are you assuming that `position` is in attribute slot zero instead of querying the slot via `glGetAttribLocation()`, using `layout (location)` in the GLSL, or setting the location with `glBindAttribLocation()` before shader linking?